# mod_rewrite and explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url, mod-rewrite

If I already have the explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) in my routing system, why do I need the mod_rewrite and other apache url rewriting settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not have mod_rewrite and the .htaccess file to specify what to do with an url like  `domain.com/foo/bar` the server searches for the folder `foo` and then the folder `bar` to look for the index file to show the user.

If you need it to be handled within your script, you need to first redirect the user to your base script then use explode on your query string and then proceed further. This is where mod_rewrite and .htaccess come into play.

Comment: Ah, got it. Simply saying to hide the "index.php" from url, right?

Answer (score 1):

To have Clean URLs, When URL structure is not same as the directory structure.

Some points:

> - Canonical URLs
> - Canonical Hostnames
> - Moved DocumentRoot
> - Search pages in more than one directory
> - Set Environment Variables According To URL Parts
> - Content Handling
> - Access Restrictions

For more read here: [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html)